# link button click not getting fired

Tags: asp.net, ajax, linkbutton

I am sorry I am repeating this question. Rather, I am having to repeat it. The last time I posted this, I dint get an answer. I have googled for more than 3 hrs, dint find an answer. Heres the html for the linkbutton and the modal popup. The link button is inside/on a tab panel and auto postback is set to true.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewAddress" runat="server" OnClick="lnkAddNewAddress_Click">Click Here To Add New Address</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkAddNewAddress_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                            DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlMyAddressBook" TargetControlID="lnkAddNewAddress"
                                            ViewStateMode="Enabled" >
                                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I want the clickevent of the linkbutton to fire which is not happening. However clicking on the link does open the modal popup extender (which is also something I want)... How do I get into the click event. I know that a postback is being avoided here because of the modal popup probably...but I dont the solution for it....

The code on save button:

```
  if(hdnfld.Value.ToString()!=null)
        { 
            if(hdnfld.Value.ToString()=="Save")
        {
            SaveNewAddress(); 

        }
        else
        {
            UpdateAddress();

        }




 <%@ Page StylesheetTheme="" Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmMyAccountMyProfile.aspx.cs"   Inherits="WebApplication1.frmMyAccountMyProfile" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckType(type) 
    {
        document.getElementById("hdnfld").value = type;
        alert(document.getElementById("hdnfld").value);
        return false;
    }



</script>
<link href="Styles/myStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="divwrap">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0px;">
        <tr>.........
<td>
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewAddress" runat="server" OnClientClick="return CheckType('Save');">Click Here To Add New Address</asp:LinkButton>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfld" runat="server" />
  <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkAddNewAddress_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlMyAddressBook" TargetControlID="lnkAddNewAddress"
                                                        ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

  &nbsp;...........
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CssClass="roundcorner btn" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" OnClientClick="return CheckType('Edit');" Text="Edit" />
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMyAddressBook" runat="server" BackColor="White" CssClass="roundcorner">
```

Comment: why you want to fire the click event of button. If it get fire then you can't see your popup anymore. Because of page load it will be hide itself. Please elaborate more, why you wanna fire event of button?

Comment: on the modal popup I have a button called save. This button will edit (update) the address if the client has clicked EDIT button previously. Otherwise, it (the save button) will add (insert) a new address (if the client has clicked the linkbutton (i.e. ADD) previously). I need to know what the client has clicked before he gets to the modal popup so that I can take the value in viewstate. For that I need the click event to fire so that I can put the value in viewstate in the click event.

Comment: ohhh, so you ahve same popup for save and update the address, and you just want to set the value according to which you can differentiate that user want to add a new address or update the address. m i right?

Comment: looks bad, please post the javascript function as well. and you haven't configured edit button with modal popup extender. but previously you told that it also prompt the same popup.

Comment: I have posted the javascript function also... you saw only half part of the edit... its all there..!

Comment: it seems to be fine in code. may be you have some other problems in your code. well the code works for me and surely it will work for others too. you can send me your application to make it correct. before that don't forget to mark my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use hidden field instead of viewstate, if you really want to retain some value at code behind. You can access hidden field at client side as well as in  code behind too.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewAddress" runat="server" OnClientClick="return CheckType('save');">Click Here To Add New Address</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_type" runat="server" />
```

**Javascript code**

```
function CheckType(type) {
        document.getElementById("hdf_type").value = type;
         return false;
    }
```

Access value in code behind when clicked on save button, and perform your action save or update according to value in hidden field.

```
hdf_type.Value.ToString();
```

**MORE HELP FOR YOU**

**HTML FILE SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS**

below i'm posting the whole code which is working fine for me.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckType(type) {
        document.getElementById("hdf_type").value = type;
        alert(document.getElementById("hdf_type").value);
        return false;
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>


    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewAddress" runat="server" OnClientClick="return CheckType('save');">Click Here To Add New Address</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return CheckType('edit');" Text="Click Here To Add New Address" />

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkAddNewAddress_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlMyAddressBook" TargetControlID="lnkAddNewAddress"
        ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <div id="pnlMyAddressBook" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; display: none; background-color: Gray">
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />

    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_type" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

getting value at code behind:

[image]

Comment: how would I GET the value into the hidden field??

Comment: Also, why cant I use ViewState here?

Comment: replace the word whatever with the value, you want to save. and one more thing. I ahve checked this on my machine. Its working fine here.

Comment: This is the code on Save button when I was using a viewstate
 if(ViewState["Click"]!=null)
            { 
                if(ViewState["Click"].ToString()=="Edit")
            {
                    UpdateAddress();
                    
            }
            else
            {
                    SaveNewAddress();
                   
            }

Comment: i have edited my answer. just pass the value "edit" when click on edit button. and save for other button. in code behind you can easily check that hidden filed contains "edit" or "save".

Comment: you ahve done all your work at client side. then why you want to fire the click event of button? you just ahd to set a single value. It has been done at client side. Btw viewstate also stores it value in hidden field at client side.

Comment: If it helps you. So please mark it as answer. so that others can also get some help.

Comment: How do I pass "edit"...?
I am just checking it... I'll mark it as the answer, don't worry..

Comment: you told that you have two different button for save popup and edit popup. but the popup is same. Just pass the edit in edit button and save in the button for save.

Comment: Ok, I have two buttons for bringing up the popup. ON the popup I have only one button (SAVE). 
Now, out of the 2 buttons that bring up the popup, one is actually a link button (the one in the code above)... the other is a button (Edit)... Now you know that I cant get into the click event of the link button... so I cannot pass any value there. On the Edit button I can pass "edit" but I don't know the syntax... Getting my point??

Comment: dear i updated my answer above. in which i passed "save" as an argument on click on link button for save. same this you can pass "edit" on other button. If still you can't understand. then can you show me your code? where you have stuck. just update your question with the code.

Comment: any update? i'm waiting when you'll complete your work and my answer will get mark. :P

Comment: check your value by using an alert at in the function "CheckType(type) ". or check the error console in mozilla by using key combination "ctrl+shift+j". may be you are getting any client side error.

Comment: use this one in the function at end before return false: alert(document.getElementById("hdf_type").value);       you can check the value.

Comment: nothing happening... the function is not getting called I think... no alert nothing...

Comment: I am supposed to put the javascript code(function) in the html, right??

Comment: yes, i have updated my answer. have a look on it. there isn't any need to change code in code behind. be right at client side.

Comment: now i think, you should complete your work after this edit on my answer. I have posted an screen shot of the code behind, where i can access the value of hidden field. now you have full code help. so go ahead. keep updating me.

Comment: The problem in my code is that the function is not getting called... Also, I am using a master page so the html is a little different.. I am posting my html... Please check it once...

Comment: it doesn't effect you are using a master page or content page. even you can create a javascript function on master page. and as usual you can use it in content pages.

Comment: I have posted the javascript function also... you saw only half part of the edit... its all there..!

Comment: you should check the Error Console in Mozilla by using key combination "ctrl + shift + j". I'm sure you have few errors on client side.

Comment: its really too pathetic. i have done a lots of efforts to give you right answer with right code. and you are not going to mark it as answer. huhhhhh. dont expect the help next time.

Comment: marked as answer! (I just want this to work!) Shall I send you the project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewAddress" runat="server" OnClick="lnkAddNewAddress_Click">Click Here To Add New Address</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkAddNewAddress_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="pnlMyAddressBook" TargetControlID="btnHidden">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" style="Display:none;" Text="Button"/>
```

In Code behind:

```
protected void lnkAddNewAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lnkAddNewAddress_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

    }
```

Comment: It works for me, the TargetControlID of ModalPopupExtender is set with the Button hidden and the LinkButton show the ModalPopupExtender in code behind

Comment: So what exactly am I doing here? creating a new button and keeping it hidden? (I really don't wanna disturb the UI)...

Comment: why you have set "TargetControlID="btnHidden?. while you are prompting the popup from codebehind.